# Get Table values using Eloquent Model in Laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to find username from post_id using Post_Tag table using Eloquent model. Here are the tables.

User Table

```
user_id(pk)
username
```

Post Table

```
post_id(pk)
user_id(fk)
```

Post_Tag Table

```
post_id(fk)
Tag_id(fk)
```

How can I fetch username from User table using Post_Tag table. Here is what I have tried:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

      public function user() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }
}

class PostTag extends Eloquent {

     public function post() {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
     }
}


$posts = PostTag::with('post')->where('tag_id','=','20')->get();
```

One tag belongs to Multiple posts and each post will belong to an owner/User. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relations are working this would do it:

```
PostTag::find(20)->post()->first()
                 ->user()->first()->username;
```

You say one Tag belongs to many posts, how do you choose which of the many posts you want to get the user's username?

Do you want to get all the users who have a post with some PostTag?

Edit: Try this:

```
PostTag::find(20)->with(['post', 'post.user'])->get();
```

Run this in artisan tinker or `dd` the result so you can see what is returned, I think this solves your problem. Just note that this may return a lot of data, you could use `take` instead of `get` to limit the results.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get all the users who have created posts with the same PostTag (tag_id = 20). This code will only get first post.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I was about to move to Query Builder from Eloquent. I was trying this from last two days. Btw, what do you use - Eloquent or Query Builder?

Comment: @Chopra I use the Eloquent, but I've never had to do something really complex, so it works and turns into beautiful, understandable and short code. But I can think of a couple of real life industry sized apps where Eloquent queries wouldn't be able to solve.

Comment: I am going to start a new project so was considering Eloquent. I think, I should move to Query Builder from start only. Thanks a lot. Appreciated !!

Comment: Remember you can use both, so in case you face a complex query, you can write your own queries by hand using the DB facade, use Eloquent for everything else.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll try. Btw, Eloquent is good with syntax and easy but Query builder is fast in executing. I am creating apis for mobile app. There are cases where I feel Query Builder is much better than Eloquent in terms of sending data and receiving on Mobile phones.